# Eclipse RCP Product Export using Ant

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-rcp

I am looking for a way to export the Eclipse RCP product using ant, I couldn't find a straight forward approach to achieve this (Of course after searching the web as well as our forum).

The link that I found that was more relevant to my question was "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098378/how-to-build-eclipse-rcp-application-from-product-with-ant-on-jenkins" but that doesn't say on usage of ant. Also there was a guide "http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePDEBuild/article.html" but even after trying it out, I am not able succeed in usage of Ant ni exporting the Eclipse product.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You want the PDE build (which is ant based) as listed in http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePDEBuild/article.html.  That's the right place to look, what was it not doing for your setup?

See also http://pweclipse.blogspot.com/2010/09/simple-rcp-product-build.html for an example of a basic RCP product build.  While it's ant based, you still have to use eclipse to run it:

```
eclipse/eclipse -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner \
 -buildfile eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.6.0.v20100603/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml \
 -Dbuilder=/opt/local/rcp/builder  \
 -Dbase=/opt/local/rcp/base \
 -Dtimestamp=20100924-1100
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Will provide the update after trying the above mentioned procedure.